# What is the best enterprise shopping cart available in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, e-commerce

I need something that is competitive to Volusion/Magento in terms of features. Cost is not an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've been watching the situation around shopping carts for past 5 years very closely. Imho the only carts that are worth trying :

- [jadasite](http://www.jadasite.com/)
- [konakart](http://www.konakart.com/)
- [shopizer](http://www.shopizer.com/)
- [Broadleaf Commerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/)
- [ofbiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/)

I've used all of them now. The first 3 are sort of out-of-the-box. I prefer jadasite and shopizer, because they are opensource projects and you have all the Konakart's paid features for free in Jadasite. And from what I know they are even better. You can install these shopping carts and go.

If you are skilled developer and want to spend a month or two playing with a nice technology, or you need a solution for a middle - big businesses, try [ofbiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/), because ofbiz gives you a platform for building enterprise class e-commerce solution.

Finally, [**Broadleaf Commerce**](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/) is somewhere in the middle. I [**blogged**](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/09/broadleaf-commerce-vs-apache-ofbiz.html) about it recently. Great technology stack, very experienced project lead. You have to have at least a year of java dev experience, because the way of integration and customization has "integration" nature, based on Spring beans/services/controllers or persistence entities overriding/merging/adding ... But it is very simple principle and I was able to work on a custom shopping cart even the same day when I checked out the code from svn.

Comment: fixed :-) I just installed Broadleaf, not bad indeed

Comment: Hi, Although this is Old Post, But Seems like You are very experience in e-commerce, I am gona build, or integrate java based e cart for my clinet and looking or possibilities. Do you have any thoughts in this year for what is better for middle level e car having product catalog, display, discounts, payment options like cash on delivery, Inventory , Shipment, CRM, admin and CMS.

Answer (score 3):

http://ofbiz.apache.org/

ofbiz includes;
Open Source ERP, Open Source CRM, Open Source E-Business / E-Commerce, Open Source SCM, Open Source MRP, Open Source CMMS/EAM, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

ATG is an outstanding package.  It is highly extensible, completely skinnable and very scalable.  It is used by many of the largest online retailers, has a strong network of partners and support is quite good.  ATG provide training courses for developers and architectural consultancy services. It includes integrations with advanced search, CRM, trouble ticketing and many allied functions.

All that having been said, it is closed-source, obtuse, complex, expensive and has a steep learning curve.  It uses a proprietary ORM that mimics Hibernate and other language constructs that parallel J2EE or Spring such as dependency injection, but in it's own special way.  Don't assume that your average J2EE or Spring developer will be able to pick it up quickly.

You do need to be careful of some of ATG's implementation partners, some of them are stacked with developers that have barely completed the standard ATG training program and you would be better off training your own staff.  Check their references and make sure you actually speak to past clients.

Standard disclaimers apply, I have no affiliation with ATG, *caveat emptor*.

Comment: My main problem with packages like ATG is that it's almost impossible to get experienced developers at anything like a reasonable salary - the freelance market is so lucrative that the minute you've trained an internal developer, they go and double their salary as a freelancer. If you hire those freelancers, your internal team get all antsy because they see someone who earns double their salary working alongside them...