# Open source Struts2/Spring/Hibernate projects that have high code quality?

Tags: hibernate, spring, struts2

In the line of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143088/open-source-c-projects-that-have-high-code-quality

What are some open source Struts2/Spring/Hibernate projects which I can download that implement many best-practices and have a relatively high code quality?

Comment: Aren't there any open source projects out there in struts2/spring/hibernate? :-(

Comment: Are you looking only for projects that use all three technologies, or for projects that use at least one of the technologies?

Comment: I am looking only for projects that use all three technologies.

Comment: Suarabh has given a very good link at the bottom. I am looking for more of the same. Does anyone knows any other such links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an open source  project [Shopizer](http://www.shopizer.com), which is a web sales management and e-commerce content management software. It uses Struts2/spring and Hibernate. Please go through its architecture here http://www.shopizer.com/?page_id=222

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is worth looking over, but I wouldn't consider it a high quality example (at least not of Struts2 or Hibernate). The way the struts.xml file is partitioned is one of the few good examples.

Comment: @Steven Benitez Thanks for the comment. Do you know of any other good examples?

Comment: @Steven Benitez eagerly waiting for some high-quality open source project list from you.

Comment: I'll keep my eyes open for some.

Answer (score 2):

[shopizer](http://www.shopizer.com/)

[broadleaf](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/)

[konakart](http://www.konakart.com/)

[ofbiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/)

and so on we can get some more information on [this link](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/08/open-source-projects-that-use-spring-framework/) and in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6303154/2591092)

Answer (score 1):

Try [roller weblogger](http://roller.apache.org/). Although high code quality can be subjective.